# Get all forms data from input field in codeigniter

Tags: forms, codeigniter

I have 200 input field in my page. All are radio button of group of 5. How can I get the data of input field. Names of all input field are created dynamically from database.

My code is as follows

```
$attributes = array('class' => 'result', 'id' => 'result', 'name' => 'result');
                        echo form_open('exam/result',$attributes);
                    $a = array(
                            'name'          => 'aptitude-'.$value->question_id,
                            'id'            => 'answer1',
                            'value'         => 'a',
                            'checked'       => FALSE,
                        );
                    $b = array(
                            'name'          => 'aptitude-'.$value->question_id,
                            'id'            => 'answer2',
                            'value'         => 'a',
                            'checked'       => FALSE,
                        );
                    $c = array(
                            'name'          => 'aptitude-'.$value->question_id,
                            'id'            => 'answer3',
                            'value'         => 'a',
                            'checked'       => FALSE,
                        );
                    $d = array(
                            'name'          => 'aptitude-'.$value->question_id,
                            'id'            => 'answer4',
                            'value'         => 'a',
                            'checked'       => FALSE,
                        );
                    $e = array(
                            'name'          => 'aptitude-'.$value->question_id,
                            'id'            => 'answer5',
                            'value'         => 'a',
                            'checked'       => FALSE,
                        );
                    $f = array(
                            'name'          => 'aptitude-'.$value->question_id,
                            'id'            => 'answer6',
                            'value'         => 'a',
                            'checked'       => TRUE,
                            'style'         => 'display:none'
                        );

                    echo form_radio($a); 
                    echo form_label($value->a, 'a');
                    echo "<br>";

                    echo form_radio($b); 
                    echo form_label($value->b, 'b');
                    echo "<br>";

                    echo form_radio($c); 
                    echo form_label($value->c, 'c');
                    echo "<br>";

                    echo form_radio($d); 
                    echo form_label($value->d, 'd');
                    echo "<br>";

                    echo form_radio($e); 
                    echo form_label($value->e, 'e');
                    echo "<br>";

                    echo form_radio($f); 


                    echo form_close();
```

This code will run for 200 times

Answer (score 1):

Use array name `aptitude[]`:

```
$a = array(
        'name'          => 'aptitude['.$value->question_id.']',
        'id'            => 'answer1',
        'value'         => 'a',
        'checked'       => FALSE,
    );
$b = array(
        'name'          => 'aptitude['.$value->question_id.']',
        'id'            => 'answer2',
        'value'         => 'b',
        'checked'       => FALSE,
    );
$c = array(
        'name'          => 'aptitude['.$value->question_id.']',
        'id'            => 'answer3',
        'value'         => 'c',
        'checked'       => FALSE,
    );
$d = array(
        'name'          => 'aptitude['.$value->question_id.']',
        'id'            => 'answer4',
        'value'         => 'd',
        'checked'       => FALSE,
    );
$e = array(
        'name'          => 'aptitude['.$value->question_id.']',
        'id'            => 'answer5',
        'value'         => 'e',
        'checked'       => FALSE,
    );
$f = array(
        'name'          => 'aptitude['.$value->question_id.']',
        'id'            => 'answer6',
        'value'         => 'f',
        'checked'       => TRUE,
        'style'         => 'display:none'
    );
```

Get POST value:

```
$aptitudes = $this->input->post('aptitude');

print_r($aptitudes);

// example output
[7] => a
[5] => c
[3] => f
// where [7] [5] [3] are the $value->question_id
```

Get specific POST

```
$aptitudes[5]; // output => c
```